# Passing system properties from command line to my app via gradle

Tags: java, gradle

My app needs a location for testing. I would like to pass this is in via a system property.

When running on the command line, gradle does not pass on the value:

```
./gradlew -Dfoo=bar clean cucumber
```

The Java code:

```
System.out.println("**foo(props):"+ System.getProperty("foo"));
```

The output:

```
**foo(props):null
```

I've seen some docs about this [here](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_should_i_be_handling_passing_system_properties_from_gradle_to_my_tests), but when I try and use that in my gradle script I get the following error:

> Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
>
> Deprecated dynamic property: "systemProperties" on "task ':cucumber'", value: "{jna.platform.library....".

Here's a snippet of my build.gradle:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        systemProperties = System.getProperties()
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'steps', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

How do you pass the system property to the app via Gradle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`systemProperties` needs to go inside `javaexec`:

```
task cucumber(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    args = ['-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'steps', 'src/test/resources']
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
}
```

PS: Unless you absolutely need to combine multiple concerns into a single task, always prefer task types (e.g. `JavaExec`) over methods (e.g. `javaexec`).